# React native Gradle some imports not working fine

Tags: react-native, gradle

I am in /node_modules/react-native/react.gradle

and I am getting an error in this line when trying to deploy:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutputFactory
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput.Style
```

unable to resolve class org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput.Style
@ line 12, column 8

there is an issue in those imports as a red line appear below them in vs code How can I fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS9Ui.png)

Comment: Seems like there are issues in your dependencies